# View on my android device are transparent why is that?

Tags: android, android-layout

when i`m downloading my application into my android device he display the views transparent , why is that? i try to change the theme and virtual devices but still the same. how can i fix it? also on the graphical layout the views have a little warning sign.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.runner"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

also this is my activity file:

```
enter code here <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.runner.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: You want to say when you run the app on your device? Add some code so we can help you out.

Comment: i just open regular application with one button

Comment: What is transparent, like the whole applications layout? Insert also the style.xml that you're using.

Comment: when i add background to activity and add buttons ot textviews then the views are transparent

Comment: If you use Holo theme in your styles.xml than there are transparent buttons by default. Add background for both button and textview to achieve a solid colored background for each view.

Comment: and if i want to cancel it? i can not?